# How to add nested body to fetch()

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch

How to add nested body to `fetch()` function?

I have this body:

```
{
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "latLng": {
                            "lat": 123,
                            "lng": 123
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "latLng": {
                            "lat": 123,
                            "lng": 123
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

I try with this code, but it returns me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`:

```
fetch(url, {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: {
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "latLng": {
                            "lat": 53.438679,
                            "lng": 14.520770
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "latLng": {
                            "lat": 53.450439,
                            "lng": 14.536400
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The `body` of the init object for `fetch` can be one of: a `Blob`, `BufferSource`, `FormData`, `URLSearchParams`, `USVString` (string), or `ReadableStream` object.  ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) | [spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#bodyinit))

You're not giving it any of those things. You're giving it a plain object. If you want to send **JSON**, you need to give it a string:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
// −−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            "locations": [
                {
                    "latLng": {
                        "lat": 53.438679,
                        "lng": 14.520770
                    }
                },
                {
                    "latLng": {
                        "lat": 53.450439,
                        "lng": 14.536400
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
// −−−−−−^
});
```

The reason you're getting the specific error you are is that since what you've provided isn't one of the things it expects, `fetch` is converting it to string as though you did `String(yourObject)`. On a plain object, unless you've done something to override it (which you haven't in your example), the result is `"[object Object]"`, which is invalid JSON as of the `o` in `object` after the opening `[`.

---

Remember: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.